# How to have multiple readers and writers using TCP streams (in the manner of Pub/Sub)?

Tags: sockets, rust, tcp

A TCP Stream represents a connection between one local and one remote socket, but I want to create an API that gives the impression that the user can write to one local socket, and have it read by multiple remote sockets, and also create multiple local sockets that are all reading from one remote socket. À la Pub/Sub (See the diagram [here](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html))

#### The tests

The tests show how I want my API to be used, and the expected behaviour. **The readers and writers should also work in the same way if created in separate processes**.

```
#[test]
fn single_writer_single_reader() {
    //reader 1 should print "hello world"
    create_reader(|s| {println!("reader 1 {}", s)});
    let mut writer = create_writer();
    writer.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
}

#[test]
fn multi_writer_single_reader() {
    //reader 1 should print "hello" twice
    create_reader(|s| {println!("reader 1 {}", s)});
    let mut writer1 = create_writer();
    let mut writer2 = create_writer();
    writer1.write_all(b"hello").unwrap();
    writer2.write_all(b"hello").unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
}

#[test]
fn single_writer_multi_reader() {
    //each reader should print "hello world"
    create_reader(|s| {println!("reader 1 {}", s)});
    create_reader(|s| {println!("reader 2 {}", s)});
    let mut writer = create_writer();
    writer.write_all(b"hello world").unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
}
```

#### My implementation

`create_reader` starts a new thread running a server (referred to as the "writer listener") on WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR that continuously accepts all connections and creates a new reader thread for each connection. The reader threads will wait for the "reader listener" to accept the reader, and then will continuously read from the writer, and call the callback function with each received message.

```
pub fn create_reader(callback: fn(String)) {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {listen_for_writers_and_make_readers(callback)});
}

fn listen_for_writers_and_make_readers(callback: fn(String)) {
    //listen for remote sockets that are connecting to WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR.
    let writer_listener = TcpListener::bind(WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR).expect("writer_listener: failed to bind");
    println!("writer_listener: started on {}", WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR);
    loop {
        let (stream, _) = writer_listener.accept().unwrap();
        println!("writer_listener: New writer connected");
        let _reader_thread = std::thread::spawn( move || {read_loop(stream, callback)});
    }

}

fn read_loop(stream: TcpStream, callback: fn(String)) {
    let mut incoming_stream = stream; //stream from the writer
    //wait for the reader listener to accept this reader (this is to signal the reader listener that a new reader is created)
    TcpStream::connect(READER_LISTENER_ADDR).expect("reader: failed to connect to reader listener");
    println!("reader: connected to reader listener");
    println!("reader: starting read loop");
    loop {
        let mut buf = [0; 1024];
        match incoming_stream.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(0) => {
                println!("reader: writer disconnected");
                break;
            },
            Ok(_) => {
                let msg = String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap();
                println!("reader: calling callback");
                callback(msg);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`create_writer` creates a TcpStream (known as writer) and waits for the "writer listener" to accept this connection. It then starts a new thread running a server (known as the "reader listener") on READER_LISTENER_ADDR that continuously accepts all connections and clones the writer for each one. Calling `write()` on `writer` will send the message to all readers because each cloned writer is connected to a reader, and writes to the original are propagated to the clones.

```
fn create_writer() -> TcpStream {
    //wait for the writer listener to accept this writer
    let writer = TcpStream::connect(WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR).expect("writer: failed to connect to writer listener");
    println!("writer: connected to the writer listener");
    //create a thread that listens for readers and clones the writer
    let writer_clone = writer.try_clone().unwrap();
    std::thread::spawn( move || {listen_for_readers_and_clone_writer(&writer_clone)});
    return writer
}

fn listen_for_readers_and_clone_writer(writer: &TcpStream) {
    //listen for remote sockets that are connecting to READER_LISTENER_ADDR
    let reader_listener = TcpListener::bind(READER_LISTENER_ADDR).expect("reader_listener: failed to bind");
    println!("reader_listener: started on {}", READER_LISTENER_ADDR);
    let mut writers = vec![];
    loop {
        let (_stream, _) = reader_listener.accept().unwrap();
        println!("reader_listener: New reader connected");
        writers.push(writer.try_clone().unwrap());
    }
}
```

#### The problem

The `single_writer_single_reader` test passes, but for the other tests, I get the errors:

For `multi_writer_single_reader`:

```
reader_listener: failed to bind: Os { code: 10048, kind: AddrInUse, message: "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." }
```

For `single_writer_multi_reader`:

```
writer_listener: failed to bind: Os { code: 10048, kind: AddrInUse, message: "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." }
```

Is there any way to allow multiple `TcpListener`s to `bind` to the same address? And if not, what would be the solution to this?

*edit*

I found a partial solution by giving the listeners an address range to pick from:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct AddrRange([&'static str; 10]);

static WRITER_LISTENER_ADDR_RANGE : AddrRange = AddrRange([
    "127.0.0.1:80",
    "127.0.0.1:81",
    "127.0.0.1:82",
    "127.0.0.1:83",
    "127.0.0.1:84",
    "127.0.0.1:85",
    "127.0.0.1:86",
    "127.0.0.1:87",
    "127.0.0.1:88",
    "127.0.0.1:89"
]);
static READER_LISTENER_ADDR_RANGE : AddrRange = AddrRange([
    "127.0.0.1:90",
    "127.0.0.1:91",
    "127.0.0.1:92",
    "127.0.0.1:93",
    "127.0.0.1:94",
    "127.0.0.1:95",
    "127.0.0.1:96",
    "127.0.0.1:97",
    "127.0.0.1:98",
    "127.0.0.1:99"
]);
```

Test 2 now passes, but test 3 does not create a new connection for the cloned writer as I thought it would. How can I get the `writer_listener` to detect that the writer has been cloned, and start a new `read_loop` thread in response to this?

Comment: You can't have multiple listeners on the same address/port. The standard solution it to have some kind of broker listening on that address and forwarding messages to all the clients.